# z-index and overflow doesn't work at all

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I was tried to set z-index, overflow, position absolute and rest css features but dropdown menu is still appearing in small square. thru console log, I figure out that some styles such as bootstrap-tabel.css and dropdown are conflicted between themselves and one style every time override other How could I fix it?

[This my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/libqkaSATjDVnJWj68Mq?p=preview)

css

```
.dropdown-menu>li
{   position:relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: visible;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:none;

    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -o-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -o-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;

}
.right-caret:after,.left-caret:after
{   content:"";
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.right-caret:after
{   border-left: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
.left-caret:after
{   border-right: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? How do you want it to look, can you explain?

Comment: @TheUknown so if you click on category you will dropdown menu with sublevels, this sublevels are hiding, I tried to set it visible but was unlucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the sub-menus, add `overflow:visible` to a new `.dropdown` menu class... at the top of the style.css file.

Use only one of these two examples. They will both override the conflict that the bootstrap-table.min.css file is causing in Plunker, with the menu's code.

```
.fixed-table-toolbar .dropdown-menu {
    overflow: visible ! important;
}
```

Or be more specific with the CSS selector chain, to avoid having to use the ! important override:

```
.fixed-table-toolbar #toolbar .dropdown-menu {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did it like you said but still same

Comment: Bootstrap is fighting with my original code example in Plunker. Let me edit my answer so that you can see what works with Plunker.

Comment: so the main problem in bootstrap as I can see, right?

Comment: Yes. It was overriding the styles. TheUknown posted a good screenshot of what I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Its being caused by the a css rule in bootstrap. One way to solve this is below :(Tested on your link)

```
.fixed-table-toolbar .dropdown-menu{
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

boostrap-table.min.css has `overflow:auto`. Either assign a new class or id and make it `visible` or use `!important` like above

[image]